# Maximum Likelihood estimation using steepest descent method

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, optimization, gradient-descent

Consider the observations: $x_1=-0.24,\quad x_2=0.31,\quad x_3=2.3,\quad x_4=-1.1$ sampled from a normal distribution. I want to determine the maximum likelihood estimate of the mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ for this normal distribution by solving the parameter (mean and standard deviation) maximum likelihood estimation problem using the steepest descent method.

What I have done so far:
$$min z=-log(L(\mu,\sigma))=2log(2\pi\sigma^2)+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}((-0.24-\mu)^2+(0.31-\mu)^2+(2.3-\mu)^2+(-1.1-\mu)^2)$$
$$\nabla z(\mu,\sigma)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sigma^2}((0.24+\mu)-(0.31-\mu)-(2.3-\mu)+(1.1+\mu))\\
\frac{4}{\sigma}\end{bmatrix}$$

Now since the mean and sd of these four points are equal to 0.318 and 1.443 respectively, the starting point I have chosen is $x^0=(0.2,1.3)^T$. Based on steepest descent the direction is $d^0=-\nabla z(x^0)=(0.278,-3.077)^T$.

If we move from $x^0$ in the direction $d^0$, using a step size $\alpha$ we get a new point $x^0 + \alpha d^0$. Since our goal is to minimize $z$, we will try to move to a point $x^1 = x^0 +\alpha d^0$ where $\alpha$ is chosen to approximately minimize the function along this direction. For this purpose, we evaluate the value of the function $z$ along the steepest descent direction as a function of the step size $\alpha$.

So $\phi(\alpha)=z(x^0+\alpha d^0)$. Now, the optimal value of $\alpha$ can be found by solving the one–dimensional minimization problem $\min \phi(\alpha)$.

No I'm stuck on how to proceed from here.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to approach it. @Sycorax

Comment: Some indication of which parts confuse you will help us to answer your question. For instance, are you familiar in general with steepest descent optimization, but unsure which function to optimize? Or unsure which quantities to compute in order to update the parameters?

Comment: I have added whatever I've done so far @AryaMcCarthy

Comment: @statwoman there are several algorithms to estimate step size $\alpha$. I would simply use Golden Section search. A more comprehensive approaches such as backtracking search that satisfies Wolfe conditions and all that. See here for http://www.lendek.net/teaching/opt_en/numerical%20optimization.pdf . Any standard numerical optimization book would be cover these topics.